# How to prevent PHP Code outputting the content in bold?

Tags: php, wordpress, output, customization

In my WordPress website, I have created a category template file (archive file) for showing all posts from a specific category. The code is working fine and I am getting the exact result what I need. However, there is some problem with my code (which I am unable to investigate).

The template file outputs 5 posts and the content of the first 2 posts is exactly what they are. However, the content of the remaining 3 posts appears in bold, which is strange.

Here is my code:

```php
<section class="video_categories" id="content" style="float:left;">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'category_name' => 'sponsor-spotlight',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
        );

        $obituary_query = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($obituary_query->have_posts()) : $obituary_query->the_post();
        $readMore = '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '"> Keep On Reading...</a>';
        echo '<div class="advert-div" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">'; ?>
        <h2 class="ad-title"> <?php echo '<a style="color: #333333;font-weight: 600;" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">';?> <?php the_title(); echo '</a>'; ?>
        </h2>
    <?php
        $post = get_post( $post->ID );
        $content_arr = get_extended($post->post_content);
        echo apply_filters('the_content', $content_arr['main']);
        echo $readMore;
        echo '</div><hr>';
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</section>
```

As per my investigation, the problem lies in the following lines of code because it results in outputing `<strong> </strong>` tags which enclose the content:

```php
$content_arr = get_extended($post->post_content);
echo apply_filters('the_content', $content_arr['main']);
```

Because when I do:

```php
 echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

I do not see any `<strong></strong>` tag on the front end that encloses the content.

Here is the strange output of the code I am using above.

[image]

Any help will highly be appreciated!

Comment: Do `<strong></strong>` tags actually  get outputted in the dom? Are you sure it's not just CSS?

Comment: @BrettGregson I have updated my question. You may see how the `<strong></strong>` gets outputted and this is also not a cause of CSS.

Comment: Is there anything strange when you `var_dump($content_arr)` ?

Comment: I think it has to be javascript which converts the DOM after being loaded

Comment: Can you show us your link of the website or maybe some Javascript code?

Comment: @zanderwar I do not get anything strange when I `var_dump($content_arr);` It will only output the fusion builder code that my theme is using.

Comment: @Jayr Here is a link to the page I having problem with: http://rchto.staging.wpengine.com/category/sponsor-spotlight/

Comment: Show the output of the fusion builder code to

Comment: @Jayr Refresh the page again, you will see the fusion builder code now

Comment: As far as i can see, this occurs when shortcodes are not closing properly. Have you tried to set the state to some posts as draft. If you switch each post to draft / publish you can see what post is causes this.

Comment: @Jayr Thanks. I will be getting in touch with you soon!

Answer (score 0):

Although there was no reason for the code to output `<strong></strong>` tags on the front end, so I practiced @Jayr recommendations by changing the status of each post which was showing in bold. The problem was within the content of those posts. I simply recreated new posts with the same content and my problem was resolved.

Thanks to @Jayr for his quick response!